# SQL Insert Statement - How to specify a condition on a single field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a simple form that allows a user to create a service for their business. They can also attach a deal to that service utilizing the same form.

Example:

- Service Title
- Service Price
- Service Description
- Activate Deal
- Deal Price

The are two date fields that are hidden:

1. ServiceCreated_Date
2. DealCreated_Date

My question is, since this is form is "inserting" and not updating what would be the proper way to incorporate a condition on the DealCreated_Date?

For example:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
(
    ServiceTitle
   ,ServicePrice
   ,ServiceDescription
   ,ServiceCreated_Date
   ,ActivateDeal
   ,DealPrice
   ,DealCreated_Date
) VALUES
(
    @ServiceTitle
   ,@ServicePrice
   ,@ServiceDescription
   ,GETDATE() // For ServiceCreated_Date
   ,@ActivateDeal
   ,@DealPrice
   ,???????
```

So basically, I want to use GETDATE() for the DealCreated_Date field, but ONLY if ActivateDeal is TRUE (1)

Is there an easy way to do this?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want to use a CASE statement:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
(
    ServiceTitle
   ,ServicePrice
   ,ServiceDescription
   ,ServiceCreated_Date
   ,ActivateDeal
   ,DealPrice
   ,DealCreated_Date
) VALUES
(
    @ServiceTitle
   ,@ServicePrice
   ,@ServiceDescription
   ,GETDATE() // For ServiceCreated_Date
   ,@ActivateDeal
   ,@DealPrice
   ,CASE WHEN @ActivateDeal THEN getDate() END
)
```

This should insert the current date or NULL depending on the value of @ActivateDeal.  Depending on its datatype, you may need to use CASE WHEN @ActivateDeal = 1 instead.

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9446e/1)

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. I had to append 1 as you mentioned but this worked perfectly.

Comment: @user1447679 -- np, glad it helped out!  I figured you'd need to do that :)  Best regards.

Comment: Hi again! I bet you could have predicted this next question... Is there a good way to handle the same thing when the business is updating their service? For example, the edit form... when they click "Edit". Is there a way to first check if the dealactive is true, and if it pre-existed? For example, in the UPDATE statement, if it first checks to see if ActivateDeal is TRUE, and then checks to see if DealCreated_Date is NULL, and only inserts the new date if its not null??? In this case, I'd even like to do this same check to create a "DealUpdated_Date" by checking other deal fields too